# Custom Animated Transition not working on iPhone 7 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, ios10

I have added a custom animated transitioning to a viewcontroller - presented and dismissed both but its not working in iPhone 7 Simulator (Xcode 8) but that animated transitioning is working perfectly fine in iPhone 6s and before simulators.

When runned on iPhone 7 Simulator, a white background appears while transitioning and then shows the next viewcontroller.

Don't know why its happening? Does anybody knows why?

**CODE**

```
#import "HEREINExpandAnimator.h"

#define kTransitionDuration 0.65

@interface HEREINExpandAnimator ()
{
    UIView *topView;
    UIView *bottomView;
}

@end
@implementation HEREINExpandAnimator


+ (id)animator {
    static HEREINExpandAnimator *animator = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        animator = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return animator;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return kTransitionDuration;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // From VC
    UIViewController *fromController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    CGRect fromViewFrame = fromController.view.frame;

    // To VC
    UIViewController *toController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    // Container View
    UIView* container = [transitionContext containerView];


    if (self.transitionMode == Presented) {

        //create snapshots
        topView = [fromController.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:fromViewFrame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.openingFrame.origin.y, 0, 0, 0)];
        topView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fromViewFrame.size.width, self.openingFrame.origin.y);

        //add our snapshots on top
        [container addSubview:topView];



        bottomView = [fromController.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:fromViewFrame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, fromViewFrame.size.height - self.openingFrame.origin.y - self.openingFrame.size.height , 0)];
        bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.openingFrame.origin.y + self.openingFrame.size.height, fromViewFrame.size.width, fromViewFrame.size.height - self.openingFrame.origin.y - self.openingFrame.size.height);

        [container addSubview:bottomView];



        // Take snapshot of the to viewcontroller and change the height to the opening frame.

        UIView *snapshotView = [toController.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:fromViewFrame afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        snapshotView.frame = self.openingFrame;


        [container addSubview:snapshotView];

        toController.view.alpha = 0.0;
        [self changeAlphaOfView:fromController.view withAlpha:0.0];

        [container addSubview:toController.view];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.85 initialSpringVelocity:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            //adjust the new frames

            topView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -topView.frame.size.height, topView.frame.size.width, topView.frame.size.height);
            bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, fromViewFrame.size.height, bottomView.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);

            snapshotView.frame = toController.view.frame;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //don't forget to clean up

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 animations:^{
                [snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
            }];


            toController.view.alpha = 1.0;
            [self changeAlphaOfView:fromController.view withAlpha:1.0];

            [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
        }];
    }
    else {

        UIView *snapshotView = [fromController.view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:fromController.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        [container addSubview:snapshotView];

        fromController.view.alpha = 0.0;

        [self changeAlphaOfView:toController.view withAlpha:0.0];


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.55 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1 initialSpringVelocity:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            topView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, topView.frame.size.width, topView.frame.size.height);
            bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, fromController.view.frame.size.height - bottomView.frame.size.height, bottomView.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);

            snapshotView.frame = self.openingFrame;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [snapshotView removeFromSuperview];

            fromController.view.alpha = 1.0;
            [self changeAlphaOfView:toController.view withAlpha:1.0];

            [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
        }];


    }


}




-(void)changeAlphaOfView:(UIView *)contentView withAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    contentView.backgroundColor =   [UIColor whiteColor];
    for (UIView *view in contentView.subviews) {
        view.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code? (If there is a lot of it, post it a project on github.) Thanks.

Comment: @matt I have mentioned the code

Answer (score 2):

Actually its a bug in iPhone 7 and 7Plus Simulator (Xcode 8.2.1), as its working fine in iPhone 6s and previous Simulators and also in real devices too.

Refer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63438)